# Network is blocking connection for some types of protocols

Tags: networking, router, vpn, firewall

The network that I am connected to does not allow certain types of connections, such as connections to game servers, peer to peer file sharing, streaming video from my home server, or UDP connections to a VPN service.

I can get around these blocks by connecting to a VPN service with a TCP connection, but this is not ideal for my needs.

1. What is the mechanism that is blocking these connections? Does the router I am connected to simply block certain ports? How can I verify this? How can I determine which ports my applications are using that need to be unblocked?
2. Is it possible that all of these applications are using the same type of connection, such as a UDP connection on a certain port?
3. If the network is blocking certain ports, could I reroute these types of connections to ports that are not blocked?

Comment: More likely it is your ISP ...

Comment: ISP most definitely can and do block ports.  If it’s not your router who owns the router?

Comment: Check all the devices/software could cause blocking, Windows firewall and any anti-virus software, the router your PC links to, and the router connects from outside. Or just temporarily disable the windows firewall and anti-virus software on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the mechanism that is blocking these connections?

A firewall...

> Does the router I am connected to simply block certain ports?

It's look to me, based on your description that your provider blocking UDP protocol completly.

> How can I verify this?

You can use [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) utility and try to connect to existing host outside of your network that you know for sure its IP and opened ports, for example like that

```
nc -u 1.2.3.4 12345 # substitute IP and port for the target you want to try
nc -u 1.2.3.4 1-65535 # Or you can even try range of ports
```

Another way is to use [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/) and try to scan target in question if you legally allow to do it.

```
nmap -sU -p 123,456,789 1.2.3.4 # substitute IP and port for the target you want to try
```

> How can I determine which ports my applications are using that need to be unblocked?

Usually authors of such software describes in documentation what ports they are using, but in case of close proprietary software you can try:

`netstat -anbo # On windows`
`netsat -a # On Linux`

> Is it possible that all of these applications are using the same type of connection, such as a UDP connection on a certain port?

No, each application can use any ports and protocols. It kinda like you can use a car or bicycle to move yourself from point A to B, but it doesn't means that your neighbor must do the same.

> If the network is blocking certain ports, could I reroute these types of connections to ports that are not blocked?

First that come to mind is to ask your provider, why some of your application doesn't work when you using UDP protocol, second - use intermediate host and proxy your connections through it.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say if this is a home ISP connection or a corporate network. If it's the latter, then successfully defeating their security will likely get you fired so consider what it's worth to you.

ISPs do block ports, services and protocols to non-business users. However it would be very unusual to block UDP wholesale as it would cause too many problems. More likely they block specific DNS queries and protocols. My own ISP blocks Bittorrent protocol.

Generally a VPN is your best bet, many of which use UDP protocols. The gotcha many people run afowl of is failing to set the VPN client up so that all of their DNS traffic also runs through the VPN.